# Remove multiple strings from filename and add result to dataframe in apply function in r

Tags: r, filenames, lapply, stringr

I have multiple files. I want to extract part of the filenames and add as a vector to the data frame and combine all the files in a single data frame.

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
fpath <- "Data/"
xlist = list.files(path = fpath, pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

xlist
"Data/1192-00.xlsx" "Data/343-00.xlsx"
```

I am able to combine the files with the following code

```
dfa = lapply(xlist, function(x){
  vo2 = read_excel(x)
})
vo2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dfa)
```

However, when I try to add the filenames as an "ID" vector I get an error

```
dfa = lapply(xlist, function(x){
  vo2 = read_excel(x)
  id= str_remove(x, "Data/")
  vo2= mutate(ID = id)
})
vo2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dfa)
```

```
 Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I've also tried

```
dfa = lapply(xlist, function(x){
  vo2 = read_excel(x)
  vo2$id= gsub("Data/|\\.xlsx", "", x)   #removes both "Data/" and ".xlsx"
  
})
vo2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dfa)
```

But the result is dataframe with just the id variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
I realised a rooky mistake with mutate: it wasn't part of a piped function!

```
dfa = lapply(xlist, function(x){
  vo2 = read_excel(x)
  id= gsub("Data/|\\.xlsx", "", x)
  vo2= vo2%>%
    mutate(ID= id)
})
vo2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dfa)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the correct path, you should do:

```
dfa = lapply(xlist, function(x){
   read_excel(x)%>%
   mutate(id= str_remove(x, "Data/"))
})
vo2= do.call("rbind.data.frame", dfa)
```

it actually seems you are using tidyverse:

You could consider using `map`

Comment: Thanks. I switched to using `gsub` instead of `str_remove` as I also wanted to remove ".xlsx". Is it possible to do that with a `stringr` function?

Comment: Yes, just do `str_remove(basename(x), ".xlsx")` or even use `str_replace(x, "Data/|\\.xlsx")`

Comment: Yes I do like using tidyverse solutions. They usually make sense to me and are often straight forward. I've not come across `map`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gsub` like below

```
> gsub("Data/|\\.xlsx", "", xlist)
[1] "1192-00" "343-00"
```

Comment: Thanks. that works to remove the unwanted strings, but I still get the same error for the `mutate` function.

Comment: @MarkDavies I don't think you should use `mutate` here.

Comment: Why not use `mutate` and do you have an alternative? I've used mutate in this sort of combining function before. I've added another failed attempt to the question using `vo2$id` syntax. Thanks

Comment: @MarkDavies it seems you have found the workaround with `mutate` :)